# Transformation of Queue.Queue() instance in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm dealing with some simple stuff and hence I'm new with python I would like to kindly ask about transformation Queue.Queue() instance into list.

Answer (score 1):

To extract all items from a queue, call `get_nowait` repeatedly:

```
l = []
try:
    while True:
        l.append(q.get_nowait())
except Queue.Empty:
    pass
```